# Is there any event for the Kendo ui window got focus?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

I couldnt find an event for the got focus for the Kendo window. My requirement is to refresh the grid data once it gets focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo UI is a jQuery-based UI.

There should be a **focusin** even for the element.

See http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$("#windowName").focusin(function() {
  $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
});
```